# Repeat a matrix in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

IF **A** is 4*3 matrix:

**A =**

```
0.5991        0.2336        0.0323

0.3799        0.8422        0.5569

0.8399        0.2050        0.6213

0.1740        0.2895        0.0185
```

How to repeat each row n time such that A to be a 3D matrix i.e, the third dimension is 4 as it is to be like this

**A_new** =

A(:,:,1) =

0.5991       0.2336       0.0323

0.5991       0.2336       0.0323

A(:,:,2) =

0.3799      0.8422      0.5569

0.3799      0.8422      0.5569

A(:,:,3) =

0.8399      0.2050      0.6213

0.8399      0.2050      0.6213

A(:,:,4) =

0.1740      0.2895     0.0185

0.1740      0.2895     0.0185

expecting a 3d matrix

Answer (score 3):

You can `reshape` A to be a `1*3*4` matrix, then simply repeat for as many rows as you want - two in your example.

Be wary because MATLAB is column-major, you have to do a transpose (`.'`) before the reshape to get the correct element ordering.

```
A = [0.5991        0.2336        0.0323
     0.3799        0.8422        0.5569
     0.8399        0.2050        0.6213
     0.1740        0.2895        0.0185];
 
A = reshape(A.',1,size(A,2),[]);    % "flatten" into 1*3*4
n = 2;                              % number of row repeats
A = repmat( A, n, 1, 1 );           % replicate into n*3*4
```

Output:

```
>> A

A(:,:,1) =
    0.5991    0.2336    0.0323
    0.5991    0.2336    0.0323


A(:,:,2) =
    0.3799    0.8422    0.5569
    0.3799    0.8422    0.5569


A(:,:,3) =
    0.8399    0.2050    0.6213
    0.8399    0.2050    0.6213


A(:,:,4) =
    0.1740    0.2895    0.0185
    0.1740    0.2895    0.0185
```